# flex и bootstrap4

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap4

Прошу помочь, пояснить как работать с flex в рамках bootstrap4.

Задача: имеется 3 блока, которые на десктопах и планшетах должны отображаться в строку с равной шириной, а на мобильных устройствах в колонку с максимальной шириной блока.

Код:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-fill services-4">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill services-5">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill services-6">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

У [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.3.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors) есть отзывчивые вариации flex-direction, изучив, я написал следующий код

```
<div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-sm-column">
    <div class="flex-fill services-4">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill services-5">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill services-6">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

что в моем понимании интерпретируется как: для экранов с брейкпоинтом md отображать блоки в строку, а для экранов с брейкпоинтом sm отображать блоки в колонку.

Но это не работает) на всех экранах отображается в строку.

Конечно, можно присвоить контейнеру собственный класс и в зависимости от значения брейкпоинта в медиа-запросах фактически указывать значение flex-direction. Но, я именно хочу понять логику, ведь готовые классы есть, так почему у меня они работают иначе, чем я себе представляю?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

эм, кажется проблема решилась) кто разбирается, поясните, насколько корректно я понял.
Объяснять поведение стоило, кажется, от обратного.

1. В качестве стандартного поведения задать блоку flex-direction: column
2. А уже при увеличении экрана применять flex.direction: row

То есть логика от "меньшего" к "большему", а не наоборот, верно?
Итого код, который заработал "как надо", получился следующим:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row flex-lg-row">
    <div class="flex-fill services-4">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill services-5">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill services-6">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте сетку [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) и будет вам счастье)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Контент блока</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Контент блока</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Контент блока</div>
</div>
```